# Bug with fprintf

Tags: c, printf

EDIT: Welp it appears I fixed it...

```
header[3] = str 
strcpy(header[3], str)
```

Those lines produce the same output when using printf but apparently fprintf only like strcpy.

This is my code:

```cpp
int pgmWrite( const char **header, const int **pixels, int numRows, int numCols, FILE *out )
{
    int i, j;
    printf("%s\n\n", header[3]);
    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        fprintf(out, "%s", header[i]);      

    printf("success in WRITE\n\n\n\n\n");

    for(j = 0; j < numRows; j++)
    {
        for(i = 0; i < numCols; i++)
            fprintf(out, "%d ", pixels[i][j]);

        fprintf(out, "\n"); 
    }
}
```

At the `printf` statement, `header[3]` is output as 237.

At the `fprintf` statement, `header[3]` is output as gibberish unicode characters.

If anyone wants I can add the monster that is the full program (300 lines) if you *really* want to see what everything is doing...

EDIT: here is my output when the error occurs (all this output comes from the above function)

```
P2
# baboon.pgma created by PGMA_IO::PGMA_WRITE.
512  512
s· _    .   .
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  
 (plus a couple thousand more zeroes for the rest of the image)
```

[FULL CODE FILE 1](http://pastebin.com/4Y7Wqm4c)

[FULL CODE FILE 2](http://pastebin.com/knrKs71j)

[TEST IMAGE FILE](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1myuj60x16aq45w/baboon.ascii.pgm?m=)

To produce error:   ./a.out -E 75 ./baboon.ascii.pgm testBaboon.pgm

Comment: No one wants THE full program.  We want _A_ short program that reproduces the problem.

Comment: When you say "the output is gibberish unicode characters", how are you determining that?  (Hint, notepad.exe is NOT a reliable way to determine that) How are you opening `out`?

Comment: We need to see the declaration of `FILE* out`, since given the apparent gibberish output, that might be one of the root causes.

Comment: I am opening out 2 ways. gedit and (since my output is a .pgm file) in a photo viewer.  The photo viewer can't display it and when I open it in gedit the only part that is "messed up unicode" is one line. That line specifies the maximum white "intensity" of the file. If I edit that elsewhere in the program, I can print out the new value perfectly fine until I attempt to print to the file.

Comment: @Philip Allgaier  I know it isn't as a result of the out declaration as I only receive the gibberish under set circumstances. And I'd provide a small program to recreate this....but the program requires an input file  (which would be rather hard to manually code in for you to test) since it has a separate value for every pixel in the image (the int ** pixel parameter)

Comment: Maybe `header[3]` is OK and `header[0]` etc. have gibberish. You will have to post a full program that creates the gibberish so that others can reproduce it.

Comment: let me just add my output

Comment: Most probably whatever is filling in your data is doing a bad job (leaving stuff out, overstepping array boundaries, not ending strings properly with '\0', ...)

Comment: You should initialize the memory you are allocating before using it (`malloc` is not taking care of that) and then later check before de-referencing it! And your image file wasn't properly uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** My previous example was based on an array of char* pointers, which is not what the OP has in mind (thanks at user *0605002* for pointing that out).

Below a quick sample outlining a simple test case for the issue. Using `memcpy` after `malloc`ensures that we have a valid memory block and prevents seg-faults during later access.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#define SIZE 8

int main()
{
    size_t size = sizeof(char*) * SIZE;
    char* test = "Test1234";

    char* *header = (char**) malloc(size);
    memcpy(header, "0", size);
    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        header[i] = (char*) malloc(size);
        memcpy(header[i], "0", size);  
    }

    header[0] = test;
    header[1] = "abc";

    FILE * pFile;
    pFile = fopen("myfile.txt", "w");

    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        fprintf(pFile, "%s\n", header[i]); 

    fclose (pFile);

    free(header);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When I changed it to    `fprintf(out, "%s", *header[i]);`  I got a segfault

Comment: Then, add a check before that line `if(header[i])` to check for valid memory and ensure that before that code is run, your `header` contents once got initialized to zero. I will update my example in a second.

Comment: Isn't `*header[i]` a single `char`? Using `%s` for printing a `char` may be the reason of the segfault.

Comment: @0605002 Not necessarily. In my test case above, the complete string "Test1234" is written to the file.

Comment: @PhilipAllgaier, yup, that's right. But in your code, `header` is actually an array of pointer-to-pointer-to-char, so de-referencing `header[i]` will give a string. But in the code in OP, `header` is a pointer-to-pointer-to-char, so it doesn't need to be de-referenced. There, `header[i]` is a string (pointer to char) and `*header[i]` would be a char.

Comment: @0605002 True, as well. Missed that when building my sample. Will change the code in a moment to match the OP's.